# Bug in python3 datetime

Tags: python-3.x

Python has a bug it supposed to return a week earlier at least according to https://www.epochconverter.com/weeks/2020

Can someone verify?

```
Python 3.7.8 (default, Jul  7 2020, 01:20:31) 
[Clang 8.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_801/final 366581)] on freebsd12
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os, time, datetime
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def mkTimeFromWeek (week, year):
...   return (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-" + str(week)+ "-1", "%Y-%W-%w"))
... 
>>> print(mkTimeFromWeek("33", "2020"))
2020-08-17 00:00:00
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not a bug, your source of reference counts the first week of 2020 from monday dec 30th to sunday 5th Jan.

```
Week number     From Date   To Date
Week 52, 2019   December 23, 2019   December 29, 2019
Week 01 December 30, 2019   January 5, 2020
Week 02 January 6, 2020 January 12, 2020
Week 03 January 13, 2020    January 19, 2020
```

However the python docs explain that for %W

> Week number of the year (Monday as the first day of the week) as a decimal number. All days in a new year preceding the first Monday are considered to be in week 0.

Since the first monday in Jan is the 6th, all days before that are considered week 0. So week 1 in 2020 in python datetime will start on 6th Jan 2020.

So the reason its out by 1 week is by design that all dates in a year before the first monday of the year are considered week 0 not week 1. thats why your 1 week out in your code.